# Do I need to ask my app users for permission to gather anonymous telemetry data?

Tags: privacy

I want to gather basic telemetry in my app (ex: which buttons are pressed, how long someone stays on certain pages, etc). Do I need to ask for a users permission to do this, or give them a way to opt out of it, if the data that is being collected includes no personal information at all. All it does is send the name of a metric (ex. ms_user_stayed_on_page) and sometimes a numeric value (ex. 20000 [milliseconds]). The data is then aggregated and averaged or summed up for all users, to be able to graph whats happening in the app for each minute.

Comment: In wich jurisdiction are you interested?

Comment: Mainly the USA, but its a mobile/web app so it can technically be used anywhere, I'm curious if this is an issue I would need to be wary of anywhere.

Comment: It _might_ fall foul of the GDPR, and would certainly be unpopular if discovered.  One legal issue is that it may be possible to use this data to reverse-engineer a session/tracking profile of a particular individual.

Comment: To point out the obvious, data may seem anonymous but it often is not. Researchers have repeatedly identified individuals from anonymous data. See, for example, [AOL search data leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AOL_search_data_leak) and [User 927](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AOL_search_data_leak#User_927). There are lots of other examples, like [Unique in the crowd: The privacy bounds of human mobility](https://www.nature.com/articles/srep01376) and [Unique in the Shopping Mall: On the Reidentifiability of Credit Card Metadata](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/347/6221/536.full).